# Setting up Intel C++ Compiler (ICC by Intel System Studio) on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, icc

I installed Intel System Studio 2019 Update 3 Ultimate Edition with offline installer here:

```
/opt/intel/system_studio_2019/
```

I added the compiler to path:

```
# .profile for SuSE Linux

export PATH="$PATH:/opt/intel/system_studio_2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019/linux/bin/intel64/"
```

The content of compiler directory:

```
m3@linux-2kee:/opt/intel/system_studio_2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019/linux/bin/intel64> ls
codecov  gcore-ia  gdb-ia  icc  icpc  map_opts  profdcg  profmerge  proforder  tselect  xiar  xild
```

Also, I ran this script:

```
/opt/intel/system_studio_2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019/linux/bin/compilervars.sh
```

Now, when restarting Qt Creator, it is able to auto-detect `Linux ICC` compilers, but not Intel debugger. I studied [this procedure](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/setting-up-the-build-environment-for-using-intel-c-or-fortran-compilers#iss-linux). What else should I do?

<kbd>[image: Linux ICC compilers are auto-detected]


 <sup>*Linux ICC compilers are auto-detected*</sup></kbd>

<kbd>[image: Only GNU debugger is detected, not the Intel debugger]


 <sup>*Only GNU debugger is auto-detected, not the Intel debugger*</sup></kbd>

Comment: Are you sure you do `sudo source ...`? Because `source` is not a program as `sudo` expects it. Instead `source` is a built-in command in the shell, and you can't use such commands with `sudo`. Not to mention that `sudo` is running as a process separate from the shell, and any environment variables set for that process won't be propagated to the shell.

Comment: As for your problem, since it's not automatically detected, why not manually add it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added manually `gdb-ia` inside `/opt/intel/system_studio_2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019/linux/bin/intel64/`, but Qt Creator says: **Type: Not recognized**

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right, I don't use `sudo`, I type `su` on terminal and then I run the shell script.

Comment: Do you run Qt Creator from the `su` session as well? The variable set by the script will be local to that session only, and wont be available when you exit the `su` session. Also, variables set in one shell won't automatically be available in another shell (like if you have two terminal windows, or set in one shell/terminal and then run a program from the GUI).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right. I ran the shell script as normal user (the same user who runs Qt Creator), however the problem persists

Comment: Now the important: Do you start Qt Creator from the same shell that you used to run the script? I.e. do you do `. /opt/intel/system_studio_2019/compilers_and_libraries_2019/linux/bin/compilervars.sh` directly followed by the command `qtcreator`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't notice this point. Now, I run the command `./compilervars.sh -arch intel64 -platform linux` and immediately on the same shell I run `~/Qt5.12.3/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator`. For some reason, the problem persists.